# What is alternative for `:=` in lower python version for this for-loop?

Tags: python, numpy

Can we shorter this code without using `:=` because my python version is lower than `3.8`?

```
arr = [3,2,1,0]
ml = .7
arrSum = 0
res = []
for a in reversed(arr):
    arrSum = a + ml*arrSum
    res.append(arrSum)
res[::-1]
# [4.89, 2.7, 1.0, 0.0]
```

with `:=`:

```
>>> arrSum = 0
>>> [arrSum := a + ml*arrSum for a in reversed(arr)][::-1]
[4.89, 2.7, 1.0, 0.0]
```

It's Okay If solution be with `numpy` or ... .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use e.g. `itertools`:

```
from itertools import accumulate

ml = 0.7
arr = [3, 2, 1, 0]
list(accumulate(arr[::-1], lambda x,y: ml * x + y))[::-1]
```

It gives:

```
[4.89, 2.7, 1.0, 0]
```

`numpy` is another option:

```
import numpy as np

np.convolve(ml**np.arange(len(arr)), arr[::-1])[len(arr)-1::-1]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very well explanation

Answer (score 1):

```
arrSum = 0
[arrSum := a + ml*arrSum for a in reversed(arr)][::-1]
```

could be rewritten as

```
arrsum = 0

def fn(x):
   nonlocal arrsum   # or 'global arrsum' depending on the context
   arrsum = x
   return x

[fn(a + ml*arrSum) for a in reversed(arr)][::-1]
```

Not saying that it is a good idea to do this ... but this is a direct way to simulate `:=` in an earlier Python version.

Comment: `arrsum` needs to be declared as `global` in `fn`.

Comment: Actually ... `nonlocal` may be better in this example.  It depends on whether `arrsum` is *really* a global variable or not.

Comment: Another way to maintain state is to exploit a [mutable default argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-and-the-mutable-default-argument). Or use e.g. `functools.partial` to bind a mutable object as an argument explicitly. Or use a class.

Comment: Thanks a lot, very well explanation